# I added ingredients/types of ingredients to this dish - can both of them mean the same?

Tags: meaning, plural-forms

When a noun is countable, can I use the plural form to indicate that there many different types, or should I use "types of 'noun'"?

Can both of them mean the same?

**Example 1**

> I added ingredients to this dish.

**Example 2**

> I added types of ingredients to this dish.

Comment: *I added types of ingredients to this dish* isn't a valid English utterance. But I don't know exactly how to explain *why*, since it's perfectly okay if you adjectivally qualify "types", as in *I added **several** types of ingredients to this dish.*

Comment: *I eat kinds of bread* - INVALID. *I eat **many** kinds of bread* - FINE.

Comment: "Ingredients" must mean 'several different ingredients', otherwise it would be 'an ingredient'.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from any other grammatical error, "types of ingredients" would suggest that the individual ingredients each belonged to different food groups. That may or may not be true of your recipe.

For example, an onion and a pepper might be two ingredients in a recipe, but they are not two different *types* of ingredients because they are both vegetables.